# Run a program until end of file even after an error is caught.

Tags: python-3.6, python-3.4, python-3.7

I was working on a program that takes in two files as arguments and evaluates expressions in the first file and returns the value to the second file. If an expression is caught that gives NameError, I write Not valid on the second file and keep running until EOF. 
This is my entire program:

```
import os.path as path_check
def file_evaluate(read_from, write_to):
try:
    file_read = open(read_from, "r")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print ("File not found")
file_write = open(write_to, "w")

try:
    for line in file_read:
        print(eval(line), file=file_write)
except NameError:
    print("Bad Expression", file=file_write)

def main():     
    file_to_read = input("Please enter a file to read from:")
    file_to_write= input("Please enter a file to write to:")
    if path_check.exists(file_to_read)==True:
    print("Output file is successfully created. The output is written to", file_to_write)
    file_evaluate(file_to_read, file_to_write)
else:
    print("File '",file_to_read,"' does not exist")
```

If my first file has 3 expressions

1. a+b
2. 5**6+4
3. 12/xx

The output on my second file will be 'Bad Expression'
Then it just stops. I want to run until EOF. I don't want the solution just a few hints would be enough. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the try-except block inside the for. You will be catching error per line instead per file:

```
   for line in file_read:
      try:       
          print(eval(line), file=file_write)
      except NameError:
          print("Bad Expression", file=file_write)
```